# Eviar parametro de view para action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho uma views que lista meus usuarios, está basicamente no padrão gerado pelo asp.net mvc com entity, os dados estão em uma table, e dentro desta table eu tenho um :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Aprovar cadastro", "Aprovar")
```

E tenho dentro do controller a Action:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Aprovar(int? Id)
    {
        if(Id == null){return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);}
        else { 
               //A função será implementada aqui
        }
    }
```

Basicamente eu preciso passar a Id de um usuário especifico para este controller, porém não estou obtendo sucesso.

Segue a minha view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ApegaPet.Models.ApplicationUser>
@{     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SideNavbar.cshtml";  }
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Avaliar_Ong";
}


<h2>Avaliar requisição de cadastro de Ongs</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nomerazao)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.endereco)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.telefone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomerazao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.endereco)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Aprovar cadastro", "Aprovar")
            </td>
        </tr>

    }


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que passar [o terceiro paramento igual está em sua documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Aprovar cadastro", "Aprovar", new {Id = item.id})
```

isso se chama sobrecarga de método (`overload`)

***Lista de Sobrecargas:***

- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, RouteValueDictionary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, String, String, String, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)</sup>
- <sup>[ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)</sup>

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Overload List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)</sup>

---

<sub>Uma ***observação*** sobre o seu código no método do `controller` é que esse dado pode ou não ser passado (`int?`), ou seja, não é ***obrigatório*** precisa talvez averiguar qual é a melhor opção nesse determinado caso.</sub>

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Método LinkExtensions.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [Método LinkExtensions.ActionLink (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd493068(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Por exemplo, este item.id ele tem que necessariamente estar sendo exibido na view ?

Comment: Não, @ProstetnicVogonJeltz pode ser um número escolhido mediante sua programação, só precisa seguir a mesma nomenclatura de `new { Id =`  onde o valor deve ser um inteiro. Eu coloquei assim pois imaginei que seria ele, mas, pode ser como já dito da sua programação.

Comment: @ProstetnicVogonJeltz vale lembrar que esse Id não é obrigatório, porque a sua regra permite ele ser `null`, olhando pelo `controller` `int? Id`!